# Create Function[Int, String, CaseClass] from CaseClass(Int, String)#tupled?

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala> case class Foo(x: Int, y: String)
defined class Foo
```

I'm trying to use `Foo.tupled` to create `Function2[Int, String, Foo]`:

```
scala> val fn2: Function2[Int, String, Foo] = Foo.tupled match { 
     |   case (param1, param2)  => { (param1, param2) => Foo(param1, param2) } 
     | }
<console>:18: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: ((Int, String)) => Foo
         case (param1, param2)  => { (param1, param2) => Foo(param1, param2) }
```

But, it's not working. How can I fix this broken code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what the match is supposed to do. You don't need it. To create a `Function1[(Int, String), Foo]`, use .tupled like below:

```
scala> case class Foo(x: Int, y: String)
defined class Foo

scala> val f = Foo.tupled
f: ((Int, String)) => Foo = <function1>

scala> f((1, "x"))
res0: Foo = Foo(1,x)
```

If you want a `Function2[Int, String, Foo]`, you don't need to use .tupled *at all*. The companion object of a case class with N parameters already implements the FunctionN trait.

```
scala> val x: Function2[Int, String, Foo] = Foo
x: (Int, String) => Foo = Foo

scala> :javap -c Foo$
Compiled from "<console>"
public class Foo$ extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction2<java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, Foo> implements scala.Serializable {
  public static final Foo$ MODULE$;
```